# What are the suggested widths for settings panel in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: windows-8

I am implementing a settings panel in my app per this blog. This blog indicates that there are guidelines for the preferred widths of settings panels. Where are these guidelines?

Comment: Here's a settings panel walk through for XAML developers  http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/how-to-create-windows-8-settings-pane.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flyout you use for settings can be either 346 px or 646 px wide and appear on either side of the screen depending on the system.

Documented here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770544.aspx